# Is it possible to define different styles for different screen sizes

Tags: java, android

I have an Android app which calculates poker odds ([Shufflebot](http://www.shufflebot.com) if you're interested). It displays cards on the screen that need to be big enough to tap on. A card is rendered by a CardView class and declared in the layout like so:

```
<com.shufflebot.view.CardView style="@style/CardView"
    android:id="@+id/flop1"></com.shufflebot.view.CardView>
```

The corresponding "CardView" style is declared in a res/values/styles.xml.

```
<style name="CardView">
    <item name="android:layout_width">40dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">56dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">1dp</item>
</style>
```

The CardView paints into whatever dimensions it is given. There is a lot of empty space when the app runs on a tablet so I'd like to make use of it by making the cards bigger and therefore easier to tap on.

Is it possible to define an alternative styles.xml to do this? e.g. could I define a res/values-xlarge/styles.xml (for pre Android 3.2) and a res/values-sw800dp/styles.xml where I can define an alternative version of my style? Better yet, can this file just contain the one modified style while Android goes to the original styles.xml for the other values?

When I attempt this in Eclipse I see red underlines suggesting to me that this is not supported.

The alternative is that I can define multiple versions of cards.xml, e.g. layout-xlarge/cards.xml but this seems like a lot of maintenance overhead given that the rest of the layout is the same and it's just the size of one element that needs to change.

So what is the best way of scaling one but not all elements like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer myself almost as an afterthought while looking at something else. I isolated the element which has the different style according to different screensizes, i.e. I create a card.xml in each different layout that it applies to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.shufflebot.view.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/CardViewLarge" >
</com.shufflebot.view.CardView>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.shufflebot.view.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/CardView" >
</com.shufflebot.view.CardView>
```

Then I replace instances of  in my layouts with  statements:

```
<include android:id="@+id/river" layout="@layout/card" />
```

This obviously wouldn't work if the cards had attributes other than the id which were different but that isn't the case for me. And it means that the same handful of layouts can serve different screen sizes.

Answer (score 1):

There is a section in the Android Dev Guide that focuses on [supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

It list some options as:

- Explicitly declare in the manifest which screen sizes your application supports
- Provide different layouts for different screen sizes
- Provide different bitmap drawables for different screen densities

Comment: I know I can use different layouts but I would prefer to use a different style with the same layout. Other than the size of one particular kind of view, the layout is identical. Having to cut, paste and maintain multiple identical layouts just doesn't seem right for something which a style rule should be able to do.

Comment: @locka: "Create a new directory in your project's res/ directory and name it using the format: <resources_name>-<qualifier>. <resources_name> is the standard resource name (such as drawable or layout)." I take that to mean that the documentation is just using `layout` and `drawable` as an example and it would also work with `values`.

Comment: I wish it did but it doesn't appear to as far as my experiments go.